# Is it possible to set first day of alloy-ui scheduler weekview to monday insted sunday?

Tags: yui, alloy-ui, yui-calendar

I'am using alloyui scheduler and weekview. I want to show from monday to sunday, not sunday to saturday.

Is it possible to set first day of alloy-ui scheduler weekview to monday insted sunday? I want week view to show monday first and sunday last. Is it possible?

Here is my code:

```
YUI({lang: 'nb-NO'}).use('aui-scheduler',
        function (Y) {

            new Y.Scheduler(
                    {
                        boundingBox: '#myScheduler',
                        //eventRecorder: eventRecorder,
                        date: date,
                        items: events,
                        render: true,

                        views: [
                            new Y.SchedulerWeekView({
                                isoTime: true,
                                headerView: false
                            })
                        ]

                    }
            );
        }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. For anyone need it just add `firstDayOfWeek: 1` to scheduler.